# Refused to get unsafe header "Location"

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-closure, cross-domain-policy

I have a website and my REST api server.

I do ajax post request to the REST server to create new model. Answer for this request will be "HTTP/1.1 201 Created" response with header "Location: http://myapi.com/some/path/111"
But I get error message `Refused to get unsafe header "Location"`. I know that this is because of cross domain access policy and other bla bla bla.

Does anybody knows how to fix it? Maybe I have to add "Access-Controll-Allow-SOMETHINGHERE" header to the response?

**UPD:**

Web site URL http://www.mydomain.com/

Original URI is http://api.mydomain.com/model/ and new Location URI is http://api.mydomain.com/model/211

Original URI is used for ajax POST request, which responses with new Location header.

Comment: What is the original URL and what is the new Location URL?

Answer (score 9):

It's because Location header is not exposed to calling client (in this case your ajax code) by default (it's 'unsafe'). To expose it you have to return additional header:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location
```

This way browser will expose it, so the client can read it. You can add there multiple comma separated headers. More about it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-expose-headers-response-header). [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#terminology) you can read which methods, headers & content types are safe (simple) and don't require any additional configuration.

Comment: Can you display this in the full code?

Comment: @EvanErickson it depends what backend language you use. For java when using Servlet Filter you can use `HttpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location");` In PHP I believe you could use `header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location');` However I don't recommend such manual approach. You should be using a complete component which adds support for CORS in your app and allows configuration of allowed methods / headers (for Java: https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=cors+filter&type=Repositories)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately no one told BlueSnap that. That company has a credit card api which requires you to get a response from the location headers... Why they didn't put the payload in the body of the response I will never know. They want you to parse a header. Terrible company.

Answer (score 2):

For Amazon S3 uploads (via Dropzone for instance) you need this in your CORS configuration.

```
<ExposeHeader>location</ExposeHeader>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just work around it, either by returning the new location as a value from the call or having the client code know where the newly created item is stored.

Another option is to create a proxy for the calls on the original domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
header Location: http://myapi.com/some/path/111"
```

That piece of code is completely wrong. Use it correct, or almost corret.

Try this:

```
header("Location: http://myapi.com/some/path/111");
```

or

```
header("Location: http://myapi.com/some/path/111"); exit();
```

If this not work, let me know :-)

Comment: Thanks Stian, but I know how to add Location header with PHP. The problem is in cross domain policy or something like this.
I get error `Refused to get unsafe header “Location”` in browser console, instead of going by new URI.